# Esp32Cam with Ultrasonic Sensor

Tags: c++, esp32

I wanted to make the esp32 cam capture image when the ultrasonic sensor's safety distance is less than 5 inch. Then the image will send to the database. But after run the code, the ultrasonic sensor and esp32cam are not work properly. The esp32cam keep capturing image even the ultrasonic sensor are not connected Please help me :(`

```
void loop() { 
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

distance = duration*0.034/2;  
distance_limit = distance;

Serial.println(String(duration)+" cm, " + String(distance)+" inch");
Serial.println(distance);

if (distance_limit<=5) {
if (Firebase.pushJSON(firebaseData, photoPath, jsonData)) {
  Serial.println(firebaseData.dataPath());
  Serial.println(firebaseData.pushName());
  Serial.println(firebaseData.dataPath() + "/"+ firebaseData.pushName());
}
else {
    Serial.println(firebaseData.errorReason());
}
delay(10000);
}
delay(1000);
}

String Photo2Base64() {
camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
fb = esp_camera_fb_get();  
if(!fb) {
  Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
  return "";
}
```

Comment: please, can you write me the link of the tutorial you have followed to link esp32cam and ultrasonic together

Comment: maybe you're reading random sensor data because the pin is not connected to something, or is connected to something which does not share a common ground with the board, then the pin is "floating" and will read random values due to ambient electrical noise